# Virtual Machine implemented in assembly on an x86

Tags: python, assembly, vm-implementation, fasm

I was just wondering if anybody here has written or knows where I can find a simple virtual machine written in x86 assembly, preferably Fasm, but anything would serve as an example as long as it is simple or at least well commented. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What's the [python] tag for? What kind of virtual machine?  Can you explain what you're trying to do?

Comment: When You Emphasize Each Word It Makes It Harder For Us To Locate The Salient Points. how simple can it be? would a brainf*ck interpreter qualify as a VM?

Comment: I Want To Write An Operating System Based On The Python Programming Language. It's Kernel Will Be Written In Fasm, Processes, Threads, etc. Are All Managed From Python Code. Te GUI Library Will Be Part Of Te Kernel But Window Managers etc. Would All Use Tkinter. I Want One Written In Fasm So I Can Rewrite A Subset Of Python To Use It, Then Use This New Python Dialect To Write An Assembler, So It WouldBe A Self Hosting Operating System

Answer (score 4):

A VM written in FASM? Hmm, the closest project that I can think of is [RevaForth](http://dev.ronware.org/p/reva/home), an implementation of [Forth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forth_%28programming_language%29) originally written in FASM. The author has since [switched to NASM](http://board.flatassembler.net/topic.php?p=95965#95965), but that is not much different from FASM.

Answer (score 1):

I did something like that in the past for a software protection. A great resource is definitely this essay from anormal/kindergarten on the great and still relevant +Fravia website.

http://www.woodmann.com/fravia/new_anor.htm